# using data frames with fixed values and subtraction

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, rows

I have a question regarding how to go Data Frames. I have this function, which we spent a data frame has only one column. I want a subtraction between a fixed number and value of each position of the data frame is performed. The result of this subtraction should be stored in another data frame.

```
 get_ms_ts_list<-function(ts_list){
    ms_ts_list <-nrow(ts_list)
    as.double(ts_list)
  for (i in 1:nrow(ts_list)){
    ms_ts_list[i]<-(1392217780000 - ts_list[i, ])
  }
  ms_ts_list
}
```

I get an error type 
Error in get_ms_ts_list (ts_list): 
   (list) object can not be coerced to type 'double'

and one that usually gives me after some changes is

6: In Ops.factor (1,392,217,780,000, ts_list [i]): 
   - Not meaningful for factors

Comment: sample data please. And a clearer explanation of what you are actually asking would help

Comment: Show an example of `ts_list`

Comment: You want to subtract a fixed number from a single-column dataframe? did you try `5 - data.frame(1:5)`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a data frame (with one column), and you want to subtract the values in this one-column data frame from a fixed number. You want a vector as a result

If your one-column data frame is `ts_list`, and the result you want is `ms_ts_list`, You can use this code:

```
ms_ts_list<-1392217780000 - ts_list[,1]
```

Comment: okay, but with this line of code, are all column values ​​or only the first value is walking, (sorry, are novice with R), is not should be ms_ts_list <-1392217780000 - ts_list [, i], and be inside a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

The function you wrote has several problems, the corrected function would be:

```
    get_ms_ts_list<-function(ts_list){
       ms_ts_list <- vector()
       static_num <- 1392217780000
       for (i in 1:length(ts_list[,1])){
           ms_ts_list[i] <- static_num-i
       }
       return(as.data.frame(ms_ts_list))
    }

   df <- data.frame(a=1:15)
   a <- get_ms_ts_list(df)
```

there is no need for creating a double, though you created a double but didn't assigned it to any variable.

Comment: you realize this just subtracts 1, 2, 3 ... from `static_num`, right?

Comment: yea, you can change that 1,2,3 to whatever you want, I just put it there as sample since it was not provided in the question

Comment: no.. your loop does i from 1, 2, 3,... and you are subtracting `static_num - i`

Comment: I think here only subtracts the static value, the value of i. I want to subtract the static value, the value of each column positions.

Comment: So you don't want to subtract the value inside of each cell in the dataframe from that static number, but you want to subtract the row number of the element in dataframe from your statics number??

if it's possible, provide a sample dataset and your expected outcome so I can understand better.